# Why are .xlsm files opened as read-only when .xlsx are not?

Tags: excel, read-only

I have a number of Excel files attached to SharePoint 2010 records. Those with .xlsx extensions open quite happily and can be edited and saved back, but those with .xlsm (i.e. with embedded macros) only open in read-only mode and force the user to save as a different name.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

These settings are specific to Excel installed on the users machine, not SharePoint.  If you go to the Excel options and go to Trust Center > Trust Center Settings you can modify this.  There are multiple ways to modify this for your needs.  You can trust publishers, trust locations, turn off protected view, etc.  I'd play with these settings until you find a configuration that suits your needs and that you are comfortable with security-wise.

Comment: OK, by editing the trust settings I have managed to remove an annoying message on openening the file (so I know this is working), but I still cannot get the file to open other than read-only, and thus cannot save (without re-naming). Additionally, I have some documents on a similar SharePoint repository but which were created with 2007, not 2010, and these claim to open in read-only mode but allow saing quite happily - so the difference must be in SP, not in Excel...